# onOffsetChanged method from OnOffsetChangedListener of AppBarLayout being constantly called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

I have been looking for an answer to this for days. There's not a single thing online I can use.

My problem is that when adding an OnOffsetChangedListener to the AppBarLayout, its method (onOffsetChaned) gets called over and over again, even if I'm not touching the screen. Aditionally, the values of verticalOffset never change, nor does the getHeight() value returned by the Toolbar or the AbbBarLayout.

I think it's important to add that this happens also using a master detail flow template from Android Studio without changing anything other than adding the code to the activity, so I don't think it's something in my code.

Thanks in advance.

**This is the code I'm using**

```
appbarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    appbarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            showToast(String.valueOf(appBarLayout.getHeight()));
            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                showToast("Collapsed");
            } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
                showToast("Expanded");
            } else {
               showToast("Scrolling");
            }
        }
    });
```

**And this is my XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".views.ActivityTaskList"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="start|top"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_task"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:hint="I need to..."
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                    android:theme="@style/ToolbarEditText"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDatePicker"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Fecha"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/input_layout_task"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_layout_task" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDatePicker"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/input_layout_task"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_label_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDatePicker"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tvDatePicker"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvDatePicker"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/task_list" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you solve this problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't recall. I'm not using the AppBarLayout anymore. But looking back at this code, it seems that I was incorrectly thinking that the `onOffsetChanged()` method was being constantly called because of the toasts I was showing inside it. With every offset I was showing a toast (the layout's height), and since they last a few seconds, I had a bunch of toasts queued popping one after the other. 

A better way to check would be to use something like
    
`Log.d(TAG, "onOffSetCHanged() called");` and check logs.

I don't think the method is being called without moving the Appbar

Answer (score 2):

It's too late but I'll answer in case anyone stumbles upon this issue.

It's being called every time because there is something being updated inside your layout constantly.

For example, if you have a `TextView` inside `AppBarLayout`, which you update every second (something like a countdown timer), every time the `onOffsetChanged` method will be called, but you'll see inside that the `verticalOffset` indeed is `0`.

In your case it could be due to the `EditText` cursor blinking every second.

Answer (score -1):

The AppBarLayout OffsetChangeListener gives call back for **IDLE** states which includes **VerticalOffset = 0**

Use [ControllableAppBarLayout](https://gist.github.com/skimarxall/863585dcd7abde8f4153).

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Stypox You can write a wrapper and consider the callback only if the offset is changed. That is what the library also does.

Comment: Ok, could you please edit the answer to reflect what you sain in the comment? Thank you ;-)

Comment: What in the world is ControllableAppBarLayout?